# Linked text in LaTeX table with knitr/kable

Tags: r, latex, knitr, bookdown, kableextra

I have the following dataframe:

```
site_name           | site_url
--------------------| ------------------------------------
3D Printing         | https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com
Academia            | https://academia.stackexchange.com
Amateur Radio       | https://ham.stackexchange.com
```

I want to generate a third column with the link integrated with the text. In HTML I came up with the following pseudo code:

```
df$url_name <- "[content of site_name](content of site_url)"
```

resulting in the following working program code:

```
if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
    df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(url_name = paste0("[", df[[1]], "](", df[[2]], ")"))
    knitr::kable(df)
}
```

Is there a way to this in LaTeX with `knitr` as well?

(I am preferring a solution compatible with `kableExtra`, but if this is not possible I am ready to learn whatever table package can do this.)

*** ADDED: I just noticed that the above code works within a normal .Rmd document with the yaml header `output: pdf_document`. But not in my `bookdown` project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `knitr::kable`.  It doesn't recognize that the `bookdown` project needs Markdown output, so you need to tell it that explicitly:

```
df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(url_name = paste0("[", df[[1]], "](", df[[2]], ")"))
knitr::kable(df, format = "markdown")
```

This will work for any kind of Markdown output:  `html_document`, `pdf_document`, `bookdown::pdf_book`, etc.

Alternatively, if you need LaTeX output for some other part of the table, you could write the LaTeX equivalent.  This won't work for HTML output, of course, but should be okay for the PDF targets:

```
df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(urlName = paste0("\\href{", df[[2]], "}{", df[[1]], "}"))
knitr::kable(df, format = "latex", escape = FALSE)
```

For this one I had to change the column name; underscores are special in LaTeX.  You could probably get away without doing that if you left it as `format = "markdown"`, but then you'd probably be better off using the first solution.

Comment: With your first recommendation, I didn't even to provide two different paths for HTML and LaTeX! I noticed that I could also use the pander packages: `df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(url_name = pander::pandoc.link.return(df[[2]], df[[1]]));
knitr::kable(df, format = "markdown")` which is a little more easier to read.

Comment: I've edited the answer to point out that the first solution works in lots of output formats.